# How to Get GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) for a console after CreateProcess() c++

Tags: c++, process

I am creating a multiple console based child processes using CreateProcess(). Now i have PI(Process Information) elements such as PID, PHandle, hThread, Threadid. Is it possible to get Std Handle for that console using these element.

i have tried this code but writing some garbage value in file

```
bool __fastcall ProcessController::StartProcess(unsigned short WindowPosition=0)
{
     PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
     STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};
   si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   si.wShowWindow = WindowPosition;

if(CreateProcess(NULL,TEXT(PName.t_str()),NULL,NULL,true,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
{

    PHandle         =       pi.hProcess;
    PId             =       pi.dwProcessId;
    PThreadHandle   =       pi.hThread;
    PThreadId       =       pi.dwThreadId;
    ////////////////////////////////
    HANDLE hOut;
    COORD location = {0, 0};
    char *buffer=NULL;
    DWORD numberRead;
    std::ofstream fileLog;

    buffer = new TCHAR[BUFFER_SIZE];
    fileLog.open ("C:\\Users\\SWDH\\Desktop\\hem.txt");
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, location,   &numberRead);
    fileLog << buffer ;
    free(buffer);
    fileLog.close();

    /////////////////////////////////
    SetWindowHandle();
    return true;
}
    }
```

Comment: "After CreateProcess" - do you mean that you want the output handle of the child process? Because `GetStdHandle` gets **your** handles, not your childs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `si.hStdOutput` - the stdout of the process you just started. To get this filled, put in flag `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` first (in `si.dwFlags`). Call `CloseHandle` on the other two handles immediately, as you won't need them. When you're done reading child output, close `hStdOutput` too.